# is there any way to get code completion when typing in a cell?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am new I tried
ctrl + space
and ;looked into the hints (ctrl shift P)
any help? I just tried to defined a func and code complete the name... ;P not even looking into api methods

Answer (score 0):

ah ok it's **ctrl + space**, I had a binding problem in my chrome